# method return value not visible in Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

A year or two back, Eclipse got an enhancement in the debugger which made it possible to see the value returned by a method.
This was a big improvement and a very useful feature.
However for the last several months, it seems to have disappeared. I can't see the returned value of any method, and it's very annoying.

I'm on Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) Build id: 20201210-1552 and my debugging environment is a connection to a Tomcat jvm running on a separeate server (Tomcat 9).

I have googled the issue and found nothing. I've looked in Eclipse for config related to this, but not found anything.

I don't know if this is an Eclipse bug, or something changed in my config that I can fix, or something to do with the Tomcat jvm.
Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **remote connections** showing **method results** is **disabled by default**, since in most cases it is slower than for local debugging.

In the **preferences** (*Window > Preferences*), in ***Java > Debug***, in the section at the bottom *Show method result after a step operation (if supported by the VM; may be slow)* tick the **checkbox** ***Enable for remote connections (may be even slower)*** to enable it.